# How do you override substitution operations?

Tags: perl, operator-overloading, overriding

I'm playing around with Perl and creating a *string object*. I know that this is *a very bad idea* to do in the real world. I'm doing it purely for fun.

I'm using [overload](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html) to overload standard Perl *string* operators with the standard operators you would find in most other languages.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $obj_string1 = Object::String->new("foo");
my $obj_string2 = Object::String->new("bar");
my $reg_string1 = "foobar";
my $reg_string2 = "barfu";

# Object::String "stringifies" correctly inside quotes

say "$obj_string1 $obj_string2";

# Use "+" for concatenations

say $obj_string1 + $obj_string2;                # Works
say $obj_string1 + $reg_string1 + $reg_string2  # Works

say $reg_string1 + $obj_string1                 # Still works!
say $reg_string1 + $obj_string1 + $reg_string2; # Still works!
say $reg_string1 + $reg_string2 + $obj_string1; # Does't work, of course.

# Overload math booleans with their string boolean equivalents

my $forty = Object::String(40);
my $one_hundred = "100";

if ( $forty > $one_hundred ) {    # Valid
   say "$forty is bigger than $one_hundred (in strings!)";
}

if ( $one_hundred < $forty ) {    # Also Valid
   say "$one_hundred is less than $forty (In strings!)";
}

# Some standard "string" methods

say $forty->length      # Prints 5
say $forty->reverse;    # Prints "ytrof"
say $forty;             # Prints "ytrof"
```

Now comes the hard part:

```
my $string = Object::String("I am the best programmer around!");
say $string;               # Prints "I am the best programmer around"
say $string->get_value;    # Prints "I am the best programmer around" with get_value Method

# But, it's time to speak the truth...

$string =~ s/best programer/biggest liar/;
say $string;               # Prints "I am the biggest liar around"
say $string->get_value;    # Whoops, no get_value method on scalar strings
```

As you can see, when I do my substitution, it works correctly, but returns a regular scalar string instead of an Object::String.

I am trying to figure out how to override the substitution operation. I've looked in the Perldoc, and I've gone through various Perl books (Advance Perl Programming, Intermediate Perl Programming, Perl Cookbook, etc.), but haven't found a way to override the substitution operation, so it returns an `Object::String`.

How do I override the substitution operation?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately Perl's overload support isn't very universal in the area of strings. There's many operations that overloading isn't party to; and `s///` is one of them.

I have started a module to fix this; [`overload::substr`](https://metacpan.org/pod/overload%3a%3asubstr) but as yet it's incomplete. It allows you to overload the `substr()` function for your object, but so far it doesn't yet have power to apply to `m//` or `s///`.

You might however, be able to use lvalue (or 4-argument) `substr()` on your objects as a way to cheat this; if the objects at least stringify into regular strings that can be matched upon, the substitution can be done using the `substr()`-rewrite trick.

Turn

```
$string =~ s/pattern/replacement/;
```

into

```
$string =~ m/pattern/ and substr($string, $-[0], $+[0]-$-[0]) = "replacement";
```

and then you'll have some code which will respect a `substr()` overload on the `$string` object, if you use my module above.

At some point of course it would be nice if `overload::substr` can perform that itself; I just haven't got around to writing it yet.

Comment: Would `substr($string,0) =~ s/pattern/replacement/;` do the trick?

Comment: Oh well, I could do what most languages do and have `$string_obj->sub($regex, $repl, $flags)` method that'll implement something like `$string =~ s/$regex/$repl/$flags`.

Comment: My plan is to create `Object::String`, `Object::Number`, `Object::Integer`, `Object::Array`, etc. and include methods that duplicate the basic Perl commands. You put `use Objectification;` in your program, and write in Perl in (a sort of) full object oriented style. All classes use `croak`, so Perl also becomes exception based. You pop a list or array with no members, and your program crashes. Of course, it would be easier to learn Python, but I don't want to give Guido van Rossum the satisfaction.

Comment: @DavidW. You're basically recreating `autobox` at this point.

Comment: @LeoNerd - Thanks, I never heard of autobox before. I see that `autobox::Core` uses `croak` in certain commands instead of returning `undef`, so it's exception based too. It doesn't use `overload` which is curious. I'd like to be able to use normal boolean operators. Combine this with `IO::File` for the `print` instead of using the built in autobox methods.